# Is it possible to sync all wordpress users with Salesforce?

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I am looking to sync Wordpress users with Salesforce. Is it possible to do this?

I would also like the user accounts to update in Salesforce is a user updates their profile in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Zapier, it has both SFDC and WP listed (but no existing zaps):  https://zapier.com/zapbook/apps/